# access USB devices from Chrome Extension OR Communicate with Chrome App from Web Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, content-script

I know that we can access chrome.hid.getDevices() in chrome app. but I have also heard that chrome.hid.getDevices() can only be used in chrome app.

But can we somehow access chrome.hid.getDevices() in chrome extensions. Because I need to inject scripts using Content-script so that I can use my extension functions from Web page and according to my knowledge Content-script can only be used in **Chrome Extension**.

**Is there any example to communicate with Chrome app with web pages?**

Answer (score 1):

What about maintaining both extension and apps, since apps have access to USB devices while extensions can inject scripts to web pages, you could use Message Passing, such as [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) to establish connection between extension and apps.

The first parameter for above two methods is `extensionId`, which could be set external extension/app id.

Comment: Is there any sample? or example?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed, see Xan's answer, I know nothing about chrome apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to directly call your functions from website code, you don't *need* an extension/content script as a proxy.

A specific domain can be whitelisted in [`"externally_connectable"` manifest key](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable) to be able to initiate [messaging with your app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage).

After that:

- The webpage can call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` or `.connect()` with app's ID.
- App will receive a `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` or `onConnnectExternal` event.

If listeners to those events are registered in the [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle), it will be woken up to handle them even if the app is not launched.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be create a C# application (Or whatever else that supports access to native messaging with chrome extensions) like [shown in this google example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging)

This allows you to send a message from chrome to your application and retrieve results (like JSON data or whatever else that ca be passed).

What I did when in a similar situation to you in needing to query a local database was create a NodeJS application that you could query like localhost:4949/usb?slot=1 from the extention and the NodeJS application itself accesses the USB or whatever else that is otherwise limited, gets whatever data is needed and returns it as a result using a REST API.

I didnt like the idea of Native Messaging between extention and application so the NodeJS server was a nice solution. Works over the local network with an IPv4 IP aswell like 192.168.0.16:4949

I can give a better example of how to do this if needed

Comment: Hmm.. It'll be really disappointing if this proves to be the best answer. I'd hoped someone would have found a way to make something portable, like WebUSB, `chrome.hid`, or `chrome.usb` work in a chrome extension context.

Comment: Very unlikely, youd have to post an issue on chronium as chrome is based on the open source project chronium. Setting up a NodeJS backend is actually very easy and in my opinion the easiest way to do this

Comment: I did: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823736. They decided WONTFIX. The context of this is adding Ledger support to MetaMask, and the option you propose is one we'd already considered and decided was not appropriate (https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/4204#issuecomment-394193271). I added a bounty to this question hoping someone knew of a better way (there are already a couple of ways you can use USB from web pages, and it's insane that none of them work in extensions), but it looks like there may not be.

Comment: Yeah the support for these useful things is really lacking IMO. And support seems be continually being withdrawn

Comment: This project uses Chrome Extensions + Native Messaging: https://github.com/gnaudio/jabra-browser-integration